# Access 2000 Forms - open center screen?

Tags: ms-access

How can I open an Access form so that it opens in Center screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your question but Properties >> Auto Center set to Yes.

Comment: Thanks. I was always using MoveSize for the Size and I didn't realize that I could leave blank the first two (position) parameters. Now that you mentioned AutoCenter I tried it and great!!! Only quirk is that for some reason the width (3 parameter of MoveSize) needs to be changed when using autocenter